# PyProj incorrect transformation from EPSG:25832 to EPSG:4326

Tags: coordinate-system, pyproj

I have the following code to transform coordinates:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

def transform_coordinates(coordinates):
    (x, y) = coordinates
    inProj  = Proj('EPSG:25832')
    outProj = Proj('EPSG:4326')
    lat, lon = transform(inProj,outProj,x,y)
    print(x,y, " -> ", lat, lon)
    return (lon, lat)

transform_coordinates((6559455.75409500021487474, 278682.56987731397384778))
```

I get the following:

```
6559455.754095 278682.569877314  ->  1.6901601579676362 56.71184635815745
```

When according to [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/transform?fbclid=IwAR27wJK2wrf6WrQK0HRqK97shO3Ecirm4EB-Qr1aR_7aKLRMHnEdbe1nzCE#s_srs=25832&t_srs=4326&x=278682.5698773&y=6559455.7540950), it should be (5.1333339, 59.1166659)

I could swear it was working yesterday.

**EDIT:**

```
inProj: Proj('+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs', preserve_units=True)

outProj: Proj('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs', preserve_units=True)
```

Comment: please add the exact values of inProj and outProj (preferably via a print() statement) to confirm what the program is useing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the difference between giving coordinates in northing-easting
order vs. easting-northing.

```
gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:25832 -t_srs epsg:4326
Enter X Y [Z [T]] values separated by space, and press Return.

6559455.754095 278682.569877314
56.7118463581575 1.69016015796764 0

278682.569877314 6559455.754095
5.13333392148302 59.1166659475444 0
```

Notice also that since Proj6 the axis order of officially latitude-longitude and northing-easting coordinate systems may be used in a different way than with older Proj versions. Read "Axis order issues" from https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc73_proj6_wkt2_srsbarn.

EDIT:

See the pyproj docs:
https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#axis-order-changes-in-proj-6

You can use the `Transformer` with the `always_xy` option if you want a consistent axis order.